# Writing an instance of a class in java

Tags: java, class

ClassName a = new ClassName1();

What does ClassName and ClassName1 mean?
I thought that ClassName had to equal ClassName1.

Comment: Hard to tell without more context, but it seems that `ClassName1` is subtype of `ClassName`

Comment: It's not really clear what you're trying to do, but I highly doubt "class1" needs to be a subtype of "class". Rather you should be writing `ClassName class1 = new ClassName("class1")`, or similar

Answer (score 2):

If

`public class ClassName1 extends/implements ClassName`

than it is perfectly valid.

This is how polimorphism works - you can treat given instance as it would be a solely instance of any of its superclasses or interfaces it implements.

Answer (score 0):

`ClassName` is the type of the variable `a`, which means for your problem, that `a` can represents an object of the type `ClassName` (and any other subclass of it).

So, the sentence `ClassName a = new ClassName1()` only make sense and is right if the `ClassName1` is a subclass of `ClassName`.